# HC-05 5.0 20220104 AT+INIT gives an Error [0]

Tags: bluetooth, command, init, rssi, hc-05

I bought the HC-05 version 5.0-20220104 module, but it gives AT+INIT error and when I send AT+INQ command, RSSI does not work properly and always shows FF9C constant value! I have the old 4.0-20190815 HC-05 module I bought before and it works without any problems.

When I send INIT command it gives Error [0], and after the IAC, CLASS and INQM set it takes the advertising signal  which shows the MAC address, device type and device name correctly by sending INQ, but RSSI data seems to be frozen in FF9C! Help if anyone has solved the problem??!!!

Comment: Hey. I have exactly the same problem with the same firmware version... I just cant run the AT+INIT command, so I guess it as something to do with it. All other settings are correct... Did you find a solution?